# Simple resistor circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm stuck with this simple problem (please be aware that this is my first non trivial circuit!):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuGDrW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Due to Kirchoff law (I chose clockwise as positive) I've written:
$$-i_1+i_0+i_2=0$$
$$i_4-i_5-i_0=0 $$

$$i_1-i_3-i_4=0$$
$$i_3-i_2+i_5=0$$
So I go on with $$i_1-i_2=i_4-i_5$$
$$i_1=i_3+i_4$$
Then, for tensions:
$$V_1+V_3+V_2=0$$
$$V_4+V_5+V_3=0$$
$$V_0+V_1+V_4=0$$

I obtain the system of equations:
$$i_3(R_1+R_2+R_3)+R_1 i_4+ R_2 i_5=0$$
$$i_3 R_3+ i_4R_4 + i_5 R_5=0$$
$$V_0+R_1 (i_3+i_4)+ R_4 i_4 =0$$

I've solved the problem, but trying some simulators I realize that the result is correct if all the resistors are of the same value, and completely wrong otherwise. What's the problem?
Thanks a lot for your precious help!

Comment: @try-catch-finally what I am asking here is: what's wrong in my assumption? where did i uncorrectly applied laws?

Comment: Poor translation.  "Tension" would be "voltage" in english.

Comment: I just saw the same question 2 days ago.

Comment: *Hint:* Its a balanced Wheatstone bridge so R3 could be any value - with no voltage difference between its ends the current  will always be zero. It works as long as R1/R4 = R2/R5 (not necessarily all the same value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error.
If I suppose current flows down through R3, then the second equation for tensions should follow the sign convention. It should be $$V_4+V_5-V_3=0$$, instead of
 $$V_4+V_5+V_3=0$$